# how to set a string value as a default value of a float field in django models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I couldn't set a string value as the default in a float field in my Django model. Here is my code:

```
from django.db import models

class Product(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=700, null=True)
    Price = models.FloatField(null=True)
    Screen_size = models.FloatField(max_length=300, blank=True ,default="Not mentioned by the seller" , null=True)
    Focus_type = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True ,default="Not mentioned by the seller" , null=True)
```

When I try to run the code I get this error:

```
ValueError: Field 'Screen_size' expected a number but got 'Not mentioned by the seller'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This default value will be saved into databases, and easy to understand, a string value can't be saved to a float field --- The database is statically typed.

Normally, if you want to do something like this, your should use `property` decorator.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=700, null=True)
    Price = models.FloatField(null=True)
    Screen_size = models.FloatField(blank=True ,null=True)
    Focus_type = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True ,default="Not mentioned by the seller" , null=True)

    @property
    def screen_size(self):
        if self.Screen_size is not None:
            return self.Screen_size
        return "Not mentioned by the seller"
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You can't use `max_length` in `FloatField`; it's only appliable for text fields such as `CharField`.
2. You can't set a string as the default value of a `FloatField` because `FloatField` is for numbers. If you want to mark something as "Not specified by the seller", I recommend you simply don't define a default. Since the field is `null=True`, you can use `None` whenever you want to mark a screen size as "not specified by the seller"
3. If you need `None` for something else, you can use a special value that doesn't make sense for screen sizes such as `-1`. You can define

```
    SCREEN_SIZE_NOT_SPECIFIED_BY_SELLER = -1
```

and then

```
    Screen_size = models.FloatField(max_length=300, blank=True ,default=SCREEN_SIZE_NOT_SPECIFIED_BY_SELLER , null=True)
```

EDIT: Yang HG's answer is good too; but i'd replace `Screen_Size` with `_screen_size` if you don't intend to use it (and to avoid two variables with the same name but different capitalization)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I just copy his code and didn't do more check.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Django specifically, but from what I know of general software/database design, I'd guess that it's a bad idea to supply a message as the default value for any field.

Instead, I think the correct approach is to use `null=True` and `blank=True` (as you already have) on the float field, allowing "no value" to be represented as null (i.e. `None`). Then, wherever your model is used, you can replace the null value with whatever message you want (including any special formatting you might want to use to indicate that the value is missing).

For the string field, [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#null) recommends against using `null=True`: for strings, you should just use the empty string to indicate "no value."

One clear benefit to this approach is that there is never a risk that a string field will have a value equal to the default message. What if a seller put in "not mentioned by the seller" as `Focus_type`? That example sounds silly, but it can be an issue in other cases.

---

Also, as a general recommendation for Python, the common convention is to use all-lowercase letters and underscores for variable names (like_this) and only capitalize class names (in CamelCase) and constants (in ALL_CAPS). Class fields should generally be capitalized as variables. If you want to learn more about conventional Python style, take a look at [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).